# PHP replace with 2 options

Tags: php

I try to delete /en. It works well:

```
$url = "myDomain/en/firstFolder/secondFolder/file.php";
echo str_replace("/en","",$url);
```

My problem comes when it could be: /en or /fr. I mean $url could be:
"myDomain/en/firstFolder/secondFolder/file.php";
"myDomain/fr/firstFolder/secondFolder/file.php";

I cannot know if I have /en or /fr. How to delete in both cases?
I tried and of course, it does not work:

```
echo str_replace("/en|/fr","",$url);
```

Comment: `str_replace(array('/fr', '/en'),"",$url);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) is able to accept an array as the first two arguments, for example (from the Docs):

> `search`
>  The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle.
>   An **array may be used to designate multiple needles**.

You can use:

```
echo str_replace( array('/en', '/fr'), '', $url );
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://eval.in/306283)

Answer (score 1):

str_replace is used to replace string, If you want to use pattern then use preg_replace

```
$url = "myDomain/fr/firstFolder/secondFolder/file.php";
echo preg_replace('/\/en|\/fr/','',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be bothered with making an array of the replacements, use a regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace('#/(en|fr|es|ru|mm)#', '', $url);
```

...and you might want to do the following to make sure you don't accidentally trim too much:

```
echo preg_replace('#/(en|fr|es|ru|mm|fi)/#', '/', $url);
```

Say your language was Finnish ('/fi') -- you would also effectively get rid of the beginning of '**/fi**rstFolder', unless you matched /fi/ with leading and trailing slashes, and substituted it with a single slash. If you can't be bothered enumerating all the languages, you can also simply...

```
echo preg_replace('#myDomain/[a-z]{2}/#', 'myDomain/', $url);
```

...which seems like the safest and most elegant way to get there.